# how to get commits from the last deploy/release in fastlane?

Tags: fastlane

For Crashlytics, I'm trying to upload release notes using:

```
 notes: changelog_from_git_commits
```

How do I limit the changelog to contain only the changes from the last release/upload?

I know that there is something between: option but that allows only using a revision or tag which is quite hard to automate. How to automate the limit to the last release?

Answer (score 1):

By default `changelog_from_git_commits` assumes your release policy involves using `git tag` to tag the code revision used to build each release. So `changelog_from_git_commits` reports the commits since the most recent tag by default.

So don't tag until you've run `changelog_from_git_commits`